# How to update the user.question_count when the user posted a question?

Tags: sqlalchemy

I'm using sqlalchemy. The question is simple, but I have a big problem, because I want to use MapperExtension.

I have two classes: User and Question

A user may have many questions, and it also contains a question_count 
to record the the count of questions belong to him.

So, when I add a new question, I want update the question_count of the 
user. At first, I do as:

```
question = Question(title='aaa', content='bbb') 
Session.add(question) 
Session.flush() 


user = question.user 
### user is not None 
user.question_count += 1 
Session.commit()
```

Everything goes well.

But I wan't to use event callback to do the same thing, so I use the `MapperExtension` of sqlalchemy. I put the logic of `updating user.question_count` in a `after_insert` callback of `question`. But I found I can't update the `user.question_count`, it will be ignored.

I don't know the reason. And, if you have the same requirement, how do you implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unit of work is computed before mapper extension is executed, so your changes to user object are left pending after transaction is committed first time. I suggest you not using ORM to update question_count, but execute SQL statement directly (use `User.__table__.update(...)` to generate statement).

Also there is a common idiom to atomically increment column: `table.update(...).values(col=table.c.col+1)` which is translated to `UPDATE ... SET col=col+1`, while your code just sets new value losing possible intermediate increments.

Comment: Actually ORM can work here, but you will need to redefine `Session.flush()` to flush twice (or more, depending on your needs). However I believe it's not the best way for your problem.